# VSCode, How to compare branches and directories and navigate through changes easily?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I want to compare git branches in [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com) open source editor, in a way that allows me navigate through the files one by one in the file explorer side pane on left, while the main screen is split into 2 screens, one for the current branch/dir and the second for the other branch/dir I want to compare against ... I want to make it very much like PhpStorm editor.

I installed an extension/plugin called [GitLens](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens), and tried to use the [Directory Compare](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens#powerful-comparison-tools) feature, but it doesn't work ...

Now my question: how to compare directories and git branches and navigate throughout the files one by one to know what has changed?

Comment: "but it doesn't work ...": what do you see? An error message? Is your directory actually different between branches?

Comment: It creates 2 empty windows

Comment: Don't you see some warning, as in https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/117#issue-243198133?

Comment: No .. Nothing like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, as in [issue 117](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/117); that you are not comparing the same branch.

And [issue 57](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/57) mentions that git difftool needs to be set first (and [it cannot be vscode itself](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6898#issuecomment-297044092)).